# ZXing QR code scanner not work on Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, qr-code, zxing

I have an APP implemented with Xamarin platform. And have QR code scan function supported by ZXing.

Everything works fine on Android. But for iOS. I have tried [iPhone 14 @ iOS 17, iPhone 15 @ iOS 17] both doesn't work on focus function.

After surf on the internet check information from other guy. Looks like this was due to ZXing has stop maintenance for new iOS/iPhone.

What I want to know is. Do we know what is the restriction exactly?

Ex: Doesn't work above iOS 16, or doen't work on model above iPhone 14.

I want to know the restriction to implement a temporary warning message on my APP.

Thank you!